# Show the Google Chrome tray icon after accidentally hiding it

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, notification-area

I have right clicked the Chrome tray icon and accidentally clicked 'Hide from tray' instead of 'Quit'. I tried looking into 'Task bar' -> 'Notification area - select which icons appear on task bar', but Chrome is not in there.

Answer (score 5):

Go to Settings > System and check the box to "Continue running background applications when Google Chrome is closed". That should bring the icon back.

Comment: I don't think this does the trick...

Comment: The exact wording for this setting nowadays is "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed"

Answer (score -3):

Right click on the bottom of the screen and choose "always show shelf" and it should reappear!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to SU. Please see the [guidelines for answers](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer). You should [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1777587/edit) the answer to add some context that validates the claim. You can add some documentation, a screenshot etc.